# How can I adapt an existing query to only count working days?

Tags: postgresql, date

I need to adapt the below query so that the measurements between date1 and date2 only counts working days (Monday-Friday), and exclude the weekends.

```
select [other columns], date_part('day', Min(date1) - date2) as days_to_open
from X
where [...]
group by [...]
```

I've looked up many answers but I don't understand how to put them within an existing query like the one above.

I'm not an experienced user so apologies if this is trivial. Using postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

```
select [other columns], date_part('day', Min(date1) - date2 + (sum(CASE extract(DOW from date2)::int % 6 WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )||' day')::interval ) as days_to_open
from X
where [...]
group by [...]
```

This use of sum(), cast as an [interval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) of days, tells the query to add back in the number of Saturdays and Sundays over the difference in dates.  The `dow` datepart is "day-of-week", which is 0 for Sundays and 6 for Saturdays, meaning that weekends are defined by the `dow` modulo 6 equalling zero.